# Is there a way to use the & on the same line as the parent selector?

Tags: sass

What I am trying to do is apply the same styles to a button's default state as to its focused state. So something like this, but with way more than one line of actually styling:

```
.my-button {
    color: red;
    &:focus: {
        color: red;
    }
}
```

In order to avoid having to duplicate the styling, I'm hoping I can write something like:

```
.my-button, &:focus {
    color: red;
}
```

But of course that's not how `&` works. Is there any way to do this?

I **know** I could just write `.my-button, .my-button:focus { ... }`. I'm just trying to learn if this is possible with Sass.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just use the parent selector on its own, `&, &:focus`:

```
.my-button {
    &, &:focus {
        color: red;
    }
}
```

Comment: CLEVER!!! That definitely works.